# Can anyone help me with partial derivatives using the following data?

Tags: calculus

We know that $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, then find the derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ if $f=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Can you show us what you've tried so far and where you're getting stuck? Here's a hint: substitute $r\cos\theta$ and $r\sin\theta$ into your expression for $f$, and remember that $\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, and $f=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$:

$$ \frac{df}{dr} = \frac{d}{dr}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2} $$

$$ = \frac{d}{dr}\frac{1}{(r\cos\theta)^2+(r\sin\theta)^2} $$

$$ = \frac{d}{dr}\frac{1}{r^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)} $$

$$ = \frac{d}{dr}\frac{1}{r^2} $$

$$ = -\frac{2}{r^3} . $$

If you need the solution in terms of $x$ and $y$, we have

$$ \frac{df}{dr} = -\frac{2}{r^3} $$

$$ = -\frac{2}{(r^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$

$$ = -\frac{2}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} .$$